# Best way to connect Apec RO-CTOP water filter under the sink

Tags: plumbing, water-filtration

I recently moved from the United States to Germany, and brought my water filter with me. It's an APEC RO-CTOP model, and it's meant to sit on your water faucet, with a lever to select between pass-thru mode and "direct water into the filter and out the tube" mode.

Of course the sink that came with my house doesn't have any sort of threading, so it needs to be connected elsewhere. Connecting it to the cold water main underneath the sink seems the best option.

Presumably there's some sort of in-line valve I can connect, so that I can direct water straight into the filter? I'm not sure what parts I need for this, and my German doesn't quite suffice to seek the advice of a plumber.

Can anyone provide some insight?

Comment: What makes you think you need a filter on the tap water in Germany?

Comment: A family member is sensitive to the mineral content of the water here, but that's sort of besides the point. :-)